# React Native Redux: How to link two slices?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, slice

I used this method and I swear it worked for a while but it's no longer working and when I display the value of slice_1 in a text with useSelector, I get an undefined is not an object error:

This doesn't work when I try to link the two slices but works fine otherwise:

```
const x = useSelector(state => state.slice_1.value);
.
.
.
<Text>{x}<Text>
```

trying to link the state of slice_2 to slice_1:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import slice_2 from './slice_2';

export const slice_1 = createSlice({
  name: 'slice_1',
  initialState: {
    value: slice_2 //slice_2.value doesn't work either
  },

export const {  } = slice_1.actions;
export default slice_1.reducer;
```

slice_2 in another file:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const slice_2 = createSlice({
  name: 'slice_2',
  initialState: {
    value: 0
  },
});

export const {  } = slice_2.actions;
export default slice_2.reducer;
```

Comment: `slice_2` is not a value.  It a reducer function and a bunch of action creator functions.  What you are attempting to do here fundamentally does not make sense.  It you explain the use case (why you would need to access state from `slice_2` in `slice_1`) then perhaps I can help you come up with a better solution.  Probably you need some `createSelector` that combines data from slices 1 and 2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm trying to write a quiz app with a categories screen and a quiz screen. Quiz screen displays questions depending on what category the user selects, so far easy. What I'm having problem with is that I want the quiz screen to update the category's state so that if the user changes category before answering all of the questions and comes back later to an unfinished category, the previous data should be recalled by the quiz screen and displayed the way it was before.

Comment: Sounds like maybe you want to store multiple quiz progresses simultaneously, keyed by the category (or quiz id or whatever).  That would be all in one slice.  I'm picturing something like https://pastebin.com/nQFZXtD5

Comment: Yep, exactly, I'm having problem keeping all the progresses. I tried to have a currentSlice, a slice whose state depends on what category is currently selected to be shown on the quiz screen. That's why I'm looking for a way to link slices together, so that I can fetch a slice, update its state and leave it aside for another slice to take it's place.